# Difference between getheight() and getmeasuredheight()

Tags: android, android-layout

I was going through this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html when i cam across a line stating that the height may, but do not have to, be different from the measured height, I was thinking of how can the measured height be different from height of a layout.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The methods `View#getMeasuredWidth()` and `View#getMeasuredHeight()` represents the dimensions the view wants to be, before all views in the layout are calculated and laid in the screen.

After `View#onMeasure(int, int)` and `View#onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int)`, views measurements could be change to accommodate everything. These (possible) new values are then accessible through `View#getWidth()` and `View#getHeight()`.

From the [View class reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html):

> The size of a view is expressed with a width and a height. A view actually possess two pairs of width and height values.
>
> The first pair is known as measured width and measured height. These dimensions define how big a view wants to be within its parent (see Layout for more details.) The measured dimensions can be obtained by calling getMeasuredWidth() and getMeasuredHeight().
>
> The second pair is simply known as width and height, or sometimes drawing width and drawing height. These dimensions define the actual size of the view on screen, at drawing time and after layout. These values may, but do not have to, be different from the measured width and height. The width and height can be obtained by calling getWidth() and getHeight().

Comment: Is it just me - or is it like the names are the wrong way around??  For me "measured" seems to imply the actual, real, final - measured - height!